# compress 4 byte floating point data to 1 byte

Tags: compression

I need to compress floating point numbers (4 bytes) to 1 byte(0 to 0xFF) to send to another device.  The floating point numbers range from -100000.0 to 100000.0.

The other device will decode from 1 byte back to floating point numbers.  How do it do it with minimum data loss?

Thanks, JC

Comment: Convert to byte by multiplying by 127/100000, then do the opposite to uncompress? But why not just transfer four bytes instead of one?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  The reason of transfering one byte is due to communication bandwidth.

Comment: Okay, but do realize that you can't just compress 4 bytes into 1. The maximum unique values that a byte of data can represent is 256 (2 ^ 8).

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use quantization. Divide 100000 to 127 intervals. Send the interval number to which float belongs to and a sign in lowest or highest bit

In your case the interval = 787,4
For example, you have input like 100. Send 1. Input 1000,147732. Send 2
On the device you can restore number by its interval.
The easiest solution is to restore the number as a middle of the interval. For example, every float that belongs to the first interval will be restored as 393.7
If you have some stats for digits distribution and it's not uniform, you can play around it by changing the intervals length and quantize frequent floats more precisely